# Cómo puedo mostrar los datos de un dataframe que correspondan solo a un intervalo de tiempo?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

En jupyter notebook. Con pandas.
Para mostrar los datos del dataframe de solo un año escribí :

```
df_maries_y = df_maries[(df_maries['year'] == 2010)]
df_maries_y
```

Y se muestran todos los datos solo del 2010.
Cómo hago para redactar que me muestre los datos pero dentro de un rango de tiempo. por ejemplo entre 2001 y 2003.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataset` al igual que el código que has intentado utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un AND a la hora de crear la máscara:

```
df_maries[(df_maries['year'] >= 2001) & (df_maries['year'] < 2003)]
```

También podrías utilizar [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), échale un vistazo.

Comment: Buen día, recuerda que las preguntas que no muestran un esfuerzo por parte del autor por intentar resolver sus dudas es mejor no contestarlas para no fomentar la holgazanería, además va en contra de las normas del sitio. Saludos